Polars rolling window on time series with custom filter based on the current row
How do I use polars' native API to do a rolling window on a datetime column, but filter out rows in the window based on the value of a column of the "current" row?
My polars dataframe of financial transactions has the following schema:

For each transaction and a duration d, I want to:

grab the source_acct and its timestamp
look back timestamp - d hours and get only rows whose source_acct or dest_acct matches the current source_acct
sum up all txn as amount_in when the current source_acct is equal to a row's dest_acct
do the same for amount_out but where the current src acct is the row's source_account including itself.

I tried this using map_rows but it's way too slow for a dataframe with 20M rows. I sort my df on the timestamp column, then run:
def windowing(df: pl.DataFrame, window_in_hours: int):
    d = timedelta(hours=window_in_hours)
    

    def calculate_amt(row):
        acc_no, window_end = row[0], row[1]
        
        window_start = window_end - d

        acct_window_mask = (
            (pl.col('timestamp') >= window_start) &
            (pl.col('timestamp') <= window_end) &
            (pl.col('dest_acct').eq(acc_no) | pl.col('source_acct').eq(acc_no))
        )
        window_txns = df.filter(acct_window_mask)

        amount_in = window_txns.filter(pl.col('dest_acct').eq(acc_no))['amount'].sum()
        amount_out = window_txns.filter(pl.col('source_acct').eq(acc_no))['amount'].sum()

        return (amount_in, amount_out)
    
    calculated_amounts = df.select(["source_acct", "timestamp", 'dest_acct', 'amount']).map_rows(calculate_amt)
    return df.with_columns(
        calculated_amounts['column_0'].alias('amount_in'), 
        calculated_amounts['column_1'].alias('amount_out'), 
    )

I've been trying to implement this using polars native API like .rolling() but I don't get how to do the filter step of comparing the current row's source account against the windowed transactions.
Here's a sample:
import polars as pl
from datetime import timedelta

data = {
    "timestamp": [
        "2024-01-01 10:00:00",
        "2024-01-01 10:30:00",
        "2024-01-01 11:00:00",
        "2024-01-01 11:30:00",
        "2024-01-01 12:00:00"
    ],
    "source_acct": ["A", "B", "A", "C", "A"],
    "dest_acct": ["B", "A", "C", "A", "B"],
    "amount": [100, 150, 200, 300, 250]
}

df = pl.DataFrame(data).with_columns(pl.col("timestamp").str.to_datetime())

print(windowing(df, 1))

Expected output:
┌─────────────────────┬─────────────┬───────────┬────────┬───────────┬────────────┐
│ timestamp           ┆ source_acct ┆ dest_acct ┆ amount ┆ amount_in ┆ amount_out │
│ ---                 ┆ ---         ┆ ---       ┆ ---    ┆ ---       ┆ ---        │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ str         ┆ str       ┆ i64    ┆ i64       ┆ i64        │
╞═════════════════════╪═════════════╪═══════════╪════════╪═══════════╪════════════╡
│ 2024-01-01 10:00:00 ┆ A           ┆ B         ┆ 100    ┆ 0         ┆ 100        │
│ 2024-01-01 10:30:00 ┆ B           ┆ A         ┆ 150    ┆ 100       ┆ 150        │
│ 2024-01-01 11:00:00 ┆ A           ┆ C         ┆ 200    ┆ 150       ┆ 300        │
│ 2024-01-01 11:30:00 ┆ C           ┆ A         ┆ 300    ┆ 200       ┆ 300        │
│ 2024-01-01 12:00:00 ┆ A           ┆ B         ┆ 250    ┆ 300       ┆ 450        │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────┴───────────┴────────┴───────────┴────────────┘



would be easier to help you if you could add a simple example input and output you're expecting

@roman thanks i've added a sample input and expected output

df_in = (
    df.join_where(
        df,
        pl.col.source_acct == pl.col.dest_acct_right,
        pl.col.timestamp.dt.offset_by("-1h") <= pl.col.timestamp_right,
        pl.col.timestamp >= pl.col.timestamp_right
    )
    .group_by("timestamp", "source_acct")
    .agg(amount_in = pl.col.amount_right.sum())
)

(
    df
    .join(df_in, on=["timestamp","source_acct"], how="left")
    .with_columns(
        pl.col.amount_in.fill_null(0),
        pl.col.amount
        .rolling_sum_by("timestamp", "1h", closed="both")
        .over("source_acct")
        .alias("amount_out")
    )
)

shape: (5, 6)
┌─────────────────────┬─────────────┬───────────┬────────┬───────────┬────────────┐
│ timestamp           ┆ source_acct ┆ dest_acct ┆ amount ┆ amount_in ┆ amount_out │
│ ---                 ┆ ---         ┆ ---       ┆ ---    ┆ ---       ┆ ---        │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ str         ┆ str       ┆ i64    ┆ i64       ┆ i64        │
╞═════════════════════╪═════════════╪═══════════╪════════╪═══════════╪════════════╡
│ 2024-01-01 10:00:00 ┆ A           ┆ B         ┆ 100    ┆ 0         ┆ 100        │
│ 2024-01-01 10:30:00 ┆ B           ┆ A         ┆ 150    ┆ 100       ┆ 150        │
│ 2024-01-01 11:00:00 ┆ A           ┆ C         ┆ 200    ┆ 150       ┆ 300        │
│ 2024-01-01 11:30:00 ┆ C           ┆ A         ┆ 300    ┆ 200       ┆ 300        │
│ 2024-01-01 12:00:00 ┆ A           ┆ B         ┆ 250    ┆ 300       ┆ 450        │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────┴───────────┴────────┴───────────┴────────────┘

Just for illustration, you can also do it with DuckDB sql:
import duckdb

duckdb.sql("""
    select
        d.*,
        (
            select coalesce(sum(tt.amount), 0)
            from df as tt
            where
                tt.dest_acct = d.source_acct and
                tt.timestamp between d.timestamp - interval 1 hour and d.timestamp
        ) as amount_in,
        sum(d.amount) over(
            partition by d.source_acct
            order by d.timestamp
            range between interval 1 hour preceding and current row
        ) as amount_out
    from df as d
""").pl()


thanks roman, but the join approach leads to OOM even after changing it to a LazyFrame and adding .collect(streaming=True), for a 20M df, ~8gb in size. haven't yet tried the duckdb approach

since join_where uses an inner join and this is saying a left join reduces mem usage, can your solution be applied using a left join instead?

unfortunately, join_where doesn't allow left joins yet. I think the bug you linked to describes specific problem and is not claiming that all inner joins are performance killers.

i forgot to sort the df. after sorting by the timestamp, i didn't get any OOM issues after. i still used the lazy API combined with streaming=True. i assume polars internally was able to do some optimizations after the sorting. thanks Roman! whole thing completed less than two mins.

amount_out should be equivalent to .rolling_sum_by() + .over()
amount_in is slightly more complex - if timestamp is unique, a .rolling() filter can be used.
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("amount")
      .filter(pl.col("dest_acct") == pl.col("source_acct").last())
      .sum()
      .rolling("timestamp", period="1h", closed="both")
      .alias("amount_in"),
    pl.col("amount")
      .rolling_sum_by("timestamp", window_size="1h", closed="both")
      .over("source_acct")
      .alias("amount_out")
)

shape: (5, 6)
┌─────────────────────┬─────────────┬───────────┬────────┬───────────┬────────────┐
│ timestamp           ┆ source_acct ┆ dest_acct ┆ amount ┆ amount_in ┆ amount_out │
│ ---                 ┆ ---         ┆ ---       ┆ ---    ┆ ---       ┆ ---        │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ str         ┆ str       ┆ i64    ┆ i64       ┆ i64        │
╞═════════════════════╪═════════════╪═══════════╪════════╪═══════════╪════════════╡
│ 2024-01-01 10:00:00 ┆ A           ┆ B         ┆ 100    ┆ 0         ┆ 100        │
│ 2024-01-01 10:30:00 ┆ B           ┆ A         ┆ 150    ┆ 100       ┆ 150        │
│ 2024-01-01 11:00:00 ┆ A           ┆ C         ┆ 200    ┆ 150       ┆ 300        │
│ 2024-01-01 11:30:00 ┆ C           ┆ A         ┆ 300    ┆ 200       ┆ 300        │
│ 2024-01-01 12:00:00 ┆ A           ┆ B         ┆ 250    ┆ 300       ┆ 450        │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────┴───────────┴────────┴───────────┴────────────┘

Duplicate timestamps in rolling
In cases where timestamp is not unique, pl.col("source_acct").last() will no longer refer to the value from the "current row", but to the last value from the "current window".

https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/18126

pl.Config(
    fmt_table_cell_list_len=10,
    fmt_str_lengths=100
)

df = pl.from_repr("""
┌─────────────────────┬─────────────┬───────────┬────────┐
│ timestamp           ┆ source_acct ┆ dest_acct ┆ amount │
│ ---                 ┆ ---         ┆ ---       ┆ ---    │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ str         ┆ str       ┆ i64    │
╞═════════════════════╪═════════════╪═══════════╪════════╡
│ 2024-01-01 10:00:00 ┆ A           ┆ B         ┆ 100    │
│ 2024-01-01 10:30:00 ┆ B           ┆ A         ┆ 150    │
│ 2024-01-01 11:00:00 ┆ A           ┆ C         ┆ 200    │
│ 2024-01-01 11:30:00 ┆ C           ┆ D         ┆ 300    │
│ 2024-01-01 11:30:00 ┆ B           ┆ A         ┆ 300    │
│ 2024-01-01 11:30:00 ┆ D           ┆ C         ┆ 300    │
│ 2024-01-01 12:00:00 ┆ A           ┆ B         ┆ 250    │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────┴───────────┴────────┘
""")

(df.with_row_index()
   .with_columns(
       pl.col("amount")
         .filter(pl.col("dest_acct") == pl.col("source_acct").last())
         .sum()
         .rolling("timestamp", period="1h", closed="both")
         .name.suffix("_in"),
       pl.col("source_acct")
         .rolling("timestamp", period="1h", closed="both").name.suffix("_in")
   )
)

shape: (7, 7)
┌───────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────┬───────────┬────────┬───────────┬───────────────────────────┐
│ index ┆ timestamp           ┆ source_acct ┆ dest_acct ┆ amount ┆ amount_in ┆ source_acct_in            │
│ ---   ┆ ---                 ┆ ---         ┆ ---       ┆ ---    ┆ ---       ┆ ---                       │
│ u32   ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ str         ┆ str       ┆ i64    ┆ i64       ┆ list[str]                 │
╞═══════╪═════════════════════╪═════════════╪═══════════╪════════╪═══════════╪═══════════════════════════╡
│ 0     ┆ 2024-01-01 10:00:00 ┆ A           ┆ B         ┆ 100    ┆ 0         ┆ ["A"]                     │
│ 1     ┆ 2024-01-01 10:30:00 ┆ B           ┆ A         ┆ 150    ┆ 100       ┆ ["A", "B"]                │
│ 2     ┆ 2024-01-01 11:00:00 ┆ A           ┆ C         ┆ 200    ┆ 150       ┆ ["A", "B", "A"]           │
│ 3     ┆ 2024-01-01 11:30:00 ┆ C           ┆ D         ┆ 300    ┆ 300       ┆ ["B", "A", "C", "B", "D"] │ # <- NOT OK
│ 4     ┆ 2024-01-01 11:30:00 ┆ B           ┆ A         ┆ 300    ┆ 300       ┆ ["B", "A", "C", "B", "D"] │ # <- NOT OK
│ 5     ┆ 2024-01-01 11:30:00 ┆ D           ┆ C         ┆ 300    ┆ 300       ┆ ["B", "A", "C", "B", "D"] │ # <- OK
│ 6     ┆ 2024-01-01 12:00:00 ┆ A           ┆ B         ┆ 250    ┆ 300       ┆ ["A", "C", "B", "D", "A"] │
└───────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────┴───────────┴────────┴───────────┴───────────────────────────┘

For index 3-5 pl.col("source_acct").last() is D meaning we get the wrong results for index 3 and 4.
To avoid this, a little extra work is required.
We need to first accumulate the rolling lists and then filter them in a separate step.
(
    df
    .with_row_index()
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("amount", "dest_acct")
          .rolling("timestamp", period="1h", closed="both")
          .name.suffix("_in"),
        pl.col("amount").rolling_sum_by("timestamp", "1h", closed="both")
          .over("source_acct")
          .alias("amount_out")
    )
    .with_columns(
       pl.col("amount_in").flatten().filter(
           pl.col("dest_acct_in").flatten() == pl.col("source_acct")
       )
       .sum()
       .over("index")
    )
    .drop("dest_acct_in")
)

shape: (7, 7)
┌───────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────┬───────────┬────────┬───────────┬────────────┐
│ index ┆ timestamp           ┆ source_acct ┆ dest_acct ┆ amount ┆ amount_in ┆ amount_out │
│ ---   ┆ ---                 ┆ ---         ┆ ---       ┆ ---    ┆ ---       ┆ ---        │
│ u32   ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ str         ┆ str       ┆ i64    ┆ i64       ┆ i64        │
╞═══════╪═════════════════════╪═════════════╪═══════════╪════════╪═══════════╪════════════╡
│ 0     ┆ 2024-01-01 10:00:00 ┆ A           ┆ B         ┆ 100    ┆ 0         ┆ 100        │
│ 1     ┆ 2024-01-01 10:30:00 ┆ B           ┆ A         ┆ 150    ┆ 100       ┆ 150        │
│ 2     ┆ 2024-01-01 11:00:00 ┆ A           ┆ C         ┆ 200    ┆ 150       ┆ 300        │
│ 3     ┆ 2024-01-01 11:30:00 ┆ C           ┆ D         ┆ 300    ┆ 500       ┆ 300        │
│ 4     ┆ 2024-01-01 11:30:00 ┆ B           ┆ A         ┆ 300    ┆ 0         ┆ 450        │
│ 5     ┆ 2024-01-01 11:30:00 ┆ D           ┆ C         ┆ 300    ┆ 300       ┆ 300        │
│ 6     ┆ 2024-01-01 12:00:00 ┆ A           ┆ B         ┆ 250    ┆ 300       ┆ 450        │
└───────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────┴───────────┴────────┴───────────┴────────────┘


This is definitely better than additional join. Should've looked into rolling() of course.

@roman I think it actually requires a unique timestamp - so is not a general solution. It seems Polars bunches all rows together in its rolling operations in the case of duplicate index_column values making it (impossible?) to detect the "current row".

Ah, interesting, so there’s no “resolve the ties” parameter yet.
